# KeyError: "Cannot treat the scalar component 'pv_gcr_roof' as an indexed component" when trying to create Pyomo Constraint

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, pyomo, mixed-integer-programming

I am trying to create a Pyomo Constraint that is double indexed. On one side of the equation I multiply with a scalar pyomo Paramater that is not indexed and it throws me this error: KeyError: "Cannot treat the scalar component 'pv_gcr_roof' as an indexed component". Here is the code:

```
pv_gcr_roof = 0.9
m.pv_gcr_roof = Param(initialize = pv_gcr_roof)
def pv_roofAreaLimit(m, az, tilt):
    return m.pv_roofPanelArea[az, tilt] <= pv_roofwallareaAvail.at[az, tilt] *\
        m.pv_gcr_roof
m.const_pvRoofAreaLimit = Constraint(m.r_az, m.r_tilt, rule = pv_roofAreaLimit)
```

If I replace m.pv_gcr_roof with 0.9 directly the constraint is built correctly.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Cheers Axel

Comment: I don't see a problem with your code and I just mocked it up and it ran.  Are you *sure* that this particular line is the one throwing the error and not some other usage in your model?

Comment: thanks Jeff. Yeah I find it weird too. I am pretty sure. The error originates in the last line of the shown code. When the Constraint is being created. But then when I follow it it shows me the line that only contains "m.pv_gcr_roof" and specifically says: KeyError: "Cannot treat the scalar component 'pv_gcr_roof' as an indexed component". But I am not trying to treat it as an indexed component. I will keep digging.